# Color tag not working on QPushButtons

Tags: css, qt, qt-creator, qt4.8

I am in the process of styling buttons in my user interface, using the UI designer in QT Creator 3.0.1 (with QT 4.8).  I am trying to have these buttons behave more like links on a website--without borders, and responding to mouse hovers.  Here is the stylesheet I am currently using:

```
QPushButton {
    border: none;
    color: #a8a8a8;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I thought it was pretty straightforward, but for some reason the color tag is not functioning on hovers.  To test, I tried changing the button in other ways, such as changing the background color, and that worked flawlessly.
I also tried changing the selectors to something more specific, by including an ancestor (`QWidget QPushButton:hover`) and by using the ID (`QPushButton#templateButton`), but neither have worked.

Is this a problem with the color tag, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#qpushbutton-and-images 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcheckbox

have you tried specifying hover under checked and unchecked like with the checkbox?  I think that hover may end up under those pseudo states because qpushbutton supports those states...

Comment: I've gone through the documentation, but it seems that they never use the color tag on hover states for QPushButton.  Using `checked` and `unchecked` do not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also possible to use QLabel to create clickable links. Create custom class ClickableLabel which inherits QLabel and handles mousePressEvents

```
class ClickableLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ClickableLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void clicked();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event) ;
};
```

And

```
void ClickableLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    emit clicked();
}
```

It is also probably possible to handle mouse hover events and change style of the label based on them. However, I have not tested it.

This solution has been copied from somewhere but I do not remember anymore the original source.

Comment: I'm going to go with this solution.  `QPushButton` just isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#templateButton {
    border: 0px;
    color: #a8a8a8;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: right;
}

#templateButton:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: The only difference I can see is the text-decoration and text-align, can you explain your answer a little more?  Incidentally, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony Hilyard I show you some pictures so I post another answer here.
`1.normal`
[image]

`2.hover`
[image]

`#pushButtonForgetPassword {
    border: none;
    color: #0066ff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: right;
}`

`#pushButtonForgetPassword:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}`

`pushButtonForgetPassword` would be the ID of my link button